# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' in Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS

Tags: 12.04, mysql, connection

I encountered with the **error Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' in Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS.**
So,I **uninstalled mysql 5.5** from Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS.But when **i tried to install mysql**,i was unable to install mysql.

i used the following commands to uninstall mysql:

```
 sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
 sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server-5.5 mysql-client-5.5 mysql-servercore-5.5 mysql-client-core-5.5
 sudo apt-get autoremove
 sudo apt-get autoclean
 sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
 sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql
 sudo deluser mysql
```

I used the following commands to install mysql 5.5:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.5
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

But i was encountered with the following error:

```
 AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld in      /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld at line 9: Could not open 'abstractions/mysql'
 start: Job failed to start
 invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
 dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup    error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                         Errors were encountered while processing:
mysql-server-5.5
mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When i type 'mysql' from terminal it returns the error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I tried **telnet 127.0.0.1 3306** after googling,it returned **connection refused**.

**Can anyone please suggest a solution?**

I run the **sudo apt-get install mysql-server** and got output as:

```
  Setting up mysql-server-5.6 (5.6.24-2+deb.sury.org~precise+2) ...
  * Stopping MySQL database server mysqld                                                                                                                                                                                                   [ OK ]
  * Starting MySQL database server mysqld                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      [fail]
  invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
  dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.6 (--configure):
  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
  dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
  mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.6; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.6 is not configured yet.
  dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
 No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup       error from a previous failure.                                                                                                             Errors were encountered while processing:
mysql-server-5.6
mysql-server
```

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972611/not-able-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-11) you could try removing apparmor: `sudo apt-get remove apparmor`, then `sudo dpkg --configure -a` to finish installing MySQL.

Comment: The same error occured

Comment: That  is odd; the error clearly mentions an apparmor problem. Since you have just removed apparmor, *that* error shouldn't appear. Please edit your question with the output of `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`.